# One heavy burden

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> I resemble the title of a spy movie
>    I'll try my best to make you a bit looney;
>    pretty and slick, there is always a con,
>    in the wrong hands I sure weight a ton;
>    You'll know I have many brothers if you are a reader
>    they are my followers, I am their leader;
>    Centuries old, not a scratch on my skin,
>    and when I get angry you'll fret for your kin;

What am I?

Comment: weigh instead of weight perhaps?

Comment: @PaigeMeinke nono, it's supposed to be 'weight'

Comment: Alright, just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: @PaigeMeinke feel free to ask if you have some other doubts!

Comment: Is it supposed to start "hey you" or "ehy you"

Comment: @Wen1now In my country we actually use both "versions" and i took for granted that it was the same in Engish. If it is an error, my bad (I'll edit it after some checks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you:

> The One Ring from Lord of the Rings?

I resemble the title of a spy movie

> The ring is a golden circle, as in "Kingsman: The Golden Circle"

I'll try my best to make you a bit looney;

> Possessing the ring slowly drives one mad

Pretty and slick, there is always a con,

> The ring is enchanting, but has it's own plan, leading men astray

in the wrong hands I sure weigh a ton;

> The metaphorical 'weight' or burden of the ring is spoken of often

You'll know I have many brothers if you are a reader

> This references the other rings in the books: Three rings for Elven kings under the sky, Seven for Dwarf Lords in their halls of stone, Nine for mortal men, doomed to die.

they are my followers, I am their leader;

> ...but the One Ring rules them all

Centuries old, not a scratch on my skin,

> The ring was forged long ago, and cannot be damaged except in the fires of Mount Doom

and when I get angry you'll fret for your kin;

> The ring is capable of great evil and destruction when in the hands of an angry/evil being

Comment: YES! Gongrats!!

Answer (score 5):

Are you:

> [Bondo™!](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/bondo-us/) (Filler and Resin)

I resemble the title of a spy movie:

> James Bond

I'll try my best to make you a bit looney;

> Bondo outgases Styrene while it dries - which similar to huffing glue, will make you a bit looney if you breath too much in.

pretty and slick, there is always a con:

> Bondo has a lovely pretty slick sheen, but don't stare at it too long - it'll stick to your skin and you'll be washing for the next two weeks to get it off (a con).

in the wrong hands I sure weight a ton;

> If you're not good at DIY, you can spill this stuff on your hands and get them stuck to everything. Trust me, once it's hardened on skin, it feels like your hands are weighed down by a ton.

You'll know I have many brothers if you are a reader

> If you can read the website, you'll see there are a ton of Bondo products in the same family

they are my followers, I am their leader;

> But Bondo™ was the original, it's the leader in filler products.

Centuries old, not a scratch on my skin,

> Bondo fills in the cracks and scratches. You can have a 100 year old tiled room, and still not even a crack; thanks to BONDO™®

and when I get angry you'll fret for your kin;

> According to the Bondo safety sheet: *"could cause flammable gases or vapors in the spill area to burn or explode."*. Don't anger Bondo, or it'll explode and harm your family.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I can't get rid of a tiny doubt in my mind that this isn't the answer you're after. But it felt wrong to leave such an important mystery unsolved.

Comment: Wow, ads are getting smarter!

Comment: @Bilkokuya To be honest i love your creativity, and i really like your approach too! But sorry, this is not the correct answer

Comment: @GustavoGabriel yep, we should get paid from Bondo!

Answer (score 2):

Go easy on me, this is my first post here and I know the answer gets a little weak towards the last few lines :)

I'm not sure if this still counts but:

> Originally your riddle started with "ehy you" - Au is the symbol for Gold.

So are you a

> Gold Coin?

I resemble the title of a spy movie

> A famous James Bond movie is Goldfinger.

I'll try my best to make you a bit looney;

> Refers to a gold doubloon or the Canadian coin called a loonie.

pretty and slick, there is always a con,

> Gold is pretty and slick, but can lead to greed

in the wrong hands I sure weight a ton;

> When gold is stolen in movies it's often tons of it

You'll know I have many brothers if you are a reader

> There are many other types of coins, but not sure about the reader part. Maybe in fiction, gold coins are often the currency of other societies?

they are my followers, I am their leader;

> Again, other coins exist, but gold coins are the "best"

Centuries old, not a scratch on my skin,

> Gold has been used as currency for hundreds of years and still is the standard

and when I get angry you'll fret for your kin;

> Money is the root of all evil

Comment: nice answer, sadly it is incorret! Regarding the bit about "ehy you": If it was somewhat of a hint or in anycase relative to the question, i wouldn't have edited it out!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> a condor.

I resemble the title of a spy movie

> Three Days of Condor

I'll try my best to make you a bit looney;

> Looney as in the sense to do with birds

pretty and slick, there is always a con,

> They move gracefully, and the con for condor

in the wrong hands I sure weight a ton;

> The old riddle about what weighs more, a ton of feathers or a ton of bricks?

You'll know I have many brothers if you are a reader

> There are a number of books in the series by James Grady that started with Six Days a Condor?

they are my followers, I am their leader;

> Since they are vultures they are followers of dying animals, so if you are the leader of a flock of condors they are *your* followers

Centuries old, not a scratch on my skin,

> I can't think of anything for this one.

and when I get angry you'll fret for your kin;

> If a condor is swooping around you it's a sign of death being near, so you will be worried that your kin are going to die.

Comment: Interesting answer! Not the one i'm looking for thogh, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is

> Thor's Hammer, Mjolnir

Unfortunately, I can't find the answers to every phrase, but I might be able to provide some; it's just a guess:

I'll try my best to make you a bit looney

> Thor's been regarded as a war-hungry fellow and of course, relying too much on his hammer, having a kind of special relationship with it; An insane guy!

pretty and slick, there is always a con

> The visual characteristics of the hammer, with the added 'worthiness' security measure against thieves.

in the wrong hands I sure weight a ton

> One of the most iconic features of Mjolnir.

You'll know I have many brothers if you are a reader

> probably referring to the time Loki created copies of Mjolnir from the same metal.

they are my followers, I am their leader

> Although the material was the same, they lacked Odin's enchantment and thus were not durable or strong enough.

Centuries old, not a scratch on my skin

> Mjolnir is very old, as are the Norse gods. Also, it is scratch-resistant.

and when I get angry you'll fret for your kin;

> Might be referring to immense lightning power of Mjolnir in Thor's hands.

Comment: I love this answer, and you made same very good points! But sorry, this is not correct

Comment: No problem, I look forward to the answer :-)